# How to resize an image without keeping its ratio?

Tags: node.js, resize, graphicsmagick

I'm using node gm (GraphicsMagick for node), I wonder how to resize an image (ignoring its ratio).

How to resize an image without keeping its ratio?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To me this don't work I had to add an extra parameter to make it.

```
    var gm = require('gm');

    gm('/path/to/image.jpg')
      .resize(353, 257, "!") //Add exclamation mark
      .autoOrient()
      .write('/path/to/newImage.jpg', function (err) {
        if (!err) console.log(' hooray! ');
      });
```

Answer (score 2):

Do you really want to ignore the ratio? If yes, you could simply use the example from gm's [website](http://aheckmann.github.com/gm/):

```
var gm = require('gm');

gm('/path/to/image.jpg')
  .resize(353, 257) // use your own width and height
  .autoOrient()
  .write(writeStream, function (err) {
    if (!err) console.log(' hooray! ');
  });
```

Comment: Thanks, zeMirco! I want to create user avatars, and it a quick way to resize the images uploaded by users. Or I have to let users to select area on images.